# can't understand the meaning of the line datasets[l.split()[2]].append(l)

Tags: python

I can't understand the following function while executing a python script the dataset is refering to a csv file while datasets is a dictionary so what do this line  datasets[l.split()[2]].append(l) means, never saw this kind off operation done to a dictionary

```
datasets = {'normal': [], 'pneumonia': [], 'COVID-19': []}
    for l in self.dataset:
        datasets[l.split()[2]].append(l)
    self.datasets = [
        datasets['normal'] + datasets['pneumonia'],
        datasets['COVID-19'],
    ]
    print(len(self.datasets[0]), len(self.datasets[1]))

    self.on_epoch_end()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding some `print` calls to see what `l.split()[2]` is? You can try breaking down that statement into its component parts to see what's going on.

Comment: Give us an example of `l` and it will enable someone to write a shorter explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

It splits l into a list, take the item at the second index of that list, looks for that item in the keys of dictionary datasets and then appends l to the value list associated with that key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

So I just broke it down using print statements.  I agree with papke but would add that, presumably, your 'dataset' is a 'list' data structure and that that each 'element' in that list data structure contains a first name and last name (or some other identifier) and one of three designations contained in datasets.  All this line -- datasets[l.split()[2]].append(l) -- does is split each element in your list into 3 strings, it takes the last of those strings to identify the 'key' it should use in the datasets dictionary.  Then it adds the individuals info to the datasets dictionary.

Does this help?

```
datasets = {'normal': [], 'pneumonia': [], 'COVID-19': []}

dataset = ['John Doe normal', 'Abby Rose pneumonia', 'Sammy Hagar COVID-19']

for l in dataset:
    print(l)
    print(l.split()[2])
    datasets[l.split()[2]].append(l)

print(datasets['normal'])
print(datasets['pneumonia'])
print(datasets['COVID-19'])
```

This is the output:

```
John Doe normal
normal
Abby Rose pneumonia
pneumonia
Sammy Hagar COVID-19
COVID-19
['John Doe normal']
['Abby Rose pneumonia']
['Sammy Hagar COVID-19']
```